# How can I build a monitor for detecting high cardinality metrics in DataDog automatically?

Tags: datadog

I'd like to detect all high cardinality metrics from DataDog automatically. Can I create a monitor for that?

My original idea was to iterate through all the metrics and query their tags (under `metric/summary` endpoint on DataDog), and then iterate through metric's list of tags to see if count (number of tag values) is bigger than 10.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query `sum:datadog.estimated_usage.metrics.custom.by_metric{*} by {metric_name}` on a monitor to alert on any metric going above a specific cardinality. You may not know what caused it and still need to go to the metric summary but this will ensure that you get alerted when needed.

I used this

```
{
    "name": "[Usage][CustomMetrics] Soft limit reached on metric {{metric_name.value}}",
    "type": "query alert",
    "query": "avg(last_4h):sum:datadog.estimated_usage.metrics.custom.by_metric{metric_name:*} by {metric_name} > 25000",
    "message": "{{#is_alert}}\nAlert | Metric {{metric_name.name}} cardinality has reached a soft quota.\n\n*This monitor ensures that any metric name with a cardinality above the threshold is sending an alert.\nIt ensures that admins have the right conversation with the end user and review the value of the metric.*\n\nInstructions:\n\n- Check the usage attribution page and usage page\n- Contact the team responsible for the metric or the increase\n- Use Metrics without Limits in case of emergency (when the cardinality is too high and would cost too much)\n- Review the actual value from this metric and act accordingly\n- Finally, exclude the metric_name from this monitor if going above quota is justified\n\nnn\n{{/is_alert}}\n\n{{#is_recovery}}\nRecovery | Metric {{metric_name.name}} cardinality is back in an acceptable state.\n{{/is_recovery}}",
    "tags": [
        "owner:me",
        "sku:metric",
        "standard:true",
        "type:usage_monitor"
    ],
    "options": {
        "include_tags": true,
        "thresholds": {
            "critical": 25000
        },
        "require_full_window": true,
        "notify_no_data": false
    },
    "priority": 3
}
```